# Using LayoutInflater to create dynamic view

Tags: android, xml

I have created a xml file I wish to repeat a number of times and populate within the main view.
I have read that LayoutInflater is the way to go but I am having issues getting it to work

first question. the xml item I created has a number of textview within it. Can this be done or can the xml only contain one textview?

```
ScrollView mainlayout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);    
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sightmarks_item, null);
            TextView textview1 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.id.textView1, null);
            EditText editview1 = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.id.editview1, null);
            EditText editview2= (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.id.editview2, null);
```

I am then running round a for loop on an array and setting the text for each the values above and then adding the view to the mainlayout view

Currently it is erroring on the inflated view.
am I doing this correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some problem in your code. To get the element of any view use `findViewById` method

```
ScrollView mainlayout = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView1);    
LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
TextView textview1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
EditText editview1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editview1);
EditText editview2= (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editview2);
```

Comment: for case in creating multiple views, this code seems  always get text-view in  first created view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing this the right way. First thing to know is that a Scrollview can contain only one element. Do you have a unique LinearLayout or TableLayout within your Scrollview, to encapsulate the textViews after ?

If I were you :

In your XML layout file (i named it "yourfile" here), use a hierarchy such as :

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... />
    <LinearLayout ...>
        <TextView .../>
        <TextView .../>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Then in your Activity, inflate the scrollview :

```
ScrollView mScroll = (ScrollView) getLayoutinflater().inflate(R.layout.yourfile, null)
```

Then to get the TextViews, go through your ScrollView using getChild(). For example to assign "my text" to the first textview, this should work :

```
( (TextView) ((ViewGroup) mScroll.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(0)).setText("my text");
```

To understand : if you want to reach the single LinearLayout you do

```
mScroll.getChildAt(0)
```

So to get to the first text view (first child of LinearLayout), you do

```
mScroll.getChildAt(0).getChildAt(0)
```